# struct member is not found

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, compiler-errors

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct vertex_tag{
    int visited = 0;
    int weight = FLT_MAX;
    int prev;
}vertex_t;
```

It has the three members as indicated above.

I malloc the vertex like this:

```
vertex_t * vertex[G->vertices];
    for(i=0; i < G->vertices; i++)
    {
        vertex[i] = (vertex_t*)malloc(sizeof(vertex_t));
    }
```

So I create a matrix from the struct. I then call them throughout the function I created like this:

```
vertex[i]->visited
vertex[i]->weight
vertex[i]->prev
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
error: ‘vertex_t’ has no member named ‘visited’
error: ‘vertex_t’ has no member named ‘weight’
error: ‘vertex_t’ has no member named ‘prev’
```

Can anyone help me understand why I cant do this?

Comment: That struct definition isn't valid; members can't be initialized like that.

Comment: So I cant make them equal to 0 and FLT_MAX?

Comment: @user081608: You can, but only later when you actually created the `vertex_t`: `vertex_t v; v.visited = 0; v.weight = INT_MAX;`

Comment: Okay so I can do it after the for loop in which I malloced it?

Comment: @user081608: If you malloc only one element per `vertex[i]`, why isn't `vertex` simply a `vertex_t[G->vertices]`? (`vertex_t vertex[G->vertices]`. By the way, Dijkstra?

Comment: Im sorry I dont understand what you mean and yup thats what im doing haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Okay so I can do it after the for loop in which I malloced it?

You'd do it better *in* the loop.

```
    vertex_t *vertex[G->vertices];
    for (i = 0; i < G->vertices; i++)
    {
        vertex[i] = malloc(sizeof(vertex_t));
        vertex[i]->visited = 0;
        vertex[i]->weight = FLT_MAX;
    }
```

or according to Zeta's suggestion:

```
    vertex_t vertex[G->vertices];
    for (i = 0; i < G->vertices; i++)
    {
        vertex[i].visited = 0;
        vertex[i].weight = FLT_MAX;
    }
```